# С прописной или строчной буквы пишется "закон № …" посередине предложения и без слова "Федеральный"?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Например, сначала в тексте автор пишет: "Федеральный закон от 30 ноября 2011 г. N 371-ФЗ", а потом: "согласно закону N 371-ФЗ". Во втором случае нужно писать "согласно Закону N 371-ФЗ" или "согласно закону N 371-ФЗ"?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, всё-таки с прописной, вот пишет юрист:

> Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию. В соответствии с положениями ст. 6
>   Закона от 30 ноября 2011 г. N 371-ФЗ "О федеральном бюджете на 2012
>   год и на плановый период 2013 и 2014 годов" (далее - Закон N 371-ФЗ)
>   Федеральное казначейство осуществило закрытие счетов территориальных
>   органов Федерального казначейства, открытых в учреждениях Центрального
>   банка на балансовом счете 40503 "Счета организаций, находящихся в
>   федеральной собственности.

https://wiseeconomist.ru/poleznoe/7697-realizaciya-zakona

Comment: Всё же хотелось бы знать, как правильно с точки зрения филологии. Юристы не обязательно знатоки русского языка)

Comment: Здесь действуют условности оформления юридических документов. В общем-то правильно писать не "Закон", а Федеральный закон, это его настоящее наименование, но, чтобы не повторять, обычно в скобках пишут его сокращённое название "(далее - Закон N 371-ФЗ)" или просто "Закон", но тогда имеется в виду именно этот закон, с этой же нумерацией.